# Generating an array of non-repeating integers

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to generate an array of 5 non-repeating integers in Java, but there are still repeats when I run it. Here's my code so far:

```
public int[] generateCode(){
    code[0] = (int)Math.round(Math.random()*8+1); // initialize first number so it won't be compared against 
    for(int i=1; i<code.length; i++){
        code[i] = (int)Math.round(Math.random()*8)+1;
        for(int j=0; j<i; j++){
            while(code[i]==code[j]){
                code[i] = (int)Math.round(Math.random()*8)+1;
            }
        } // end inner for loop
        
    } // end outer for loop
    return code;
    
    
} // end generateCode method
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: With every number you roll, you have to start over so that the new number won't match any previous number. You can't continue from the same j. Imagine you first generate 3 1 4, then another 1. You now check that it's not 3, which is fine. You check that it's 1, which it is, so you reroll to 3. You then check 3 != 4, and finally conclude that the number is unique. That's how you end up with 3 1 4 3.

Comment: So, your `for-loop` is checking for repeated characters, BUT each time you generate a new value (in the `while-loop`) you're not checking to see if the value exits before `j`

Comment: If you generate numbers randomly, you cannot be sure that every new number will be unique. You'd better do it the opposite way: First generate a list of candidate numbers sequentially. And then, chose them randomly dropping each selected candidate after.

Comment: Realistically, you only have a limited range of values (`1-9`) to choose from.  As LittleSanti says, create an array of those values and then randomly select an index from it

Comment: `code = new Random().ints(1, 10).distinct().limit(code.length).toArray()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, your `for-loop` is checking for repeated characters, BUT each time you generate a new value (in the `while-loop`) you're not checking to see if the value exits before `j`.

There are a number of possible ways you might address this issue, I prefer ones which uses `Collections.shuffle`, but assuming that you can't use features like `Arrays`, `Collections`, `List`, `Set` or possibly even streams, we need to work with what we have, arrays.

Since you have a small range of acceptable values which need to fit into an even smaller range, a simple solution might be to generate a "master" list of allowed values and randomly select a value from the master list, tracking which values you've already picked.

Sounds more complicated then it actually is, for example...

```
public int[] generateCode() {
    int[] masterValues = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    int[] codes = new int[5];
    
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int index = 0;
    while (index < codes.length) {
        int lookupIndex = 0;
        do {
            lookupIndex = rnd.nextInt(masterValues.length);
        } while (masterValues[lookupIndex] == 0);
        codes[index] = masterValues[lookupIndex];
        masterValues[lookupIndex] = 0;
        index++;
    }
    return codes;
}
```

This creates a "master" list of values.  It then randomly calculates a "lookup" index, checks to see if the value in the master list is `0` or not, if not, it assigns it to the next index in the `codes` array and sets the value in the master list to `0`, otherwise it generates a new random index and tries again.  This all repeats till it fills the `codes` array

So doing something like...

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(generateCode()));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(generateCode()));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(generateCode()));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(generateCode()));
```

could print (because it's "random")...

```
[8, 1, 4, 7, 5]
[9, 6, 2, 1, 8]
[6, 5, 9, 4, 7]
[2, 5, 3, 1, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are much easier ways to do this.  Using a `Set<Integer>` would be one.  Here is another.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8));
Collections.shuffle(list);
System.out.println(list.subList(0,5));
```

prints something like

```
[4, 5, 8, 2, 1]
```

As was pointed out to me, you may not be allowed to use or know about collections.  But I would recommend you at least make a helper method to check for duplicates to reduce the clutter.  Something like the following:

```
public boolean contains(int[] arr, int n) {
    for (int v : arr) {
        if (v == n) {
          return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then you can keep checking the current value to be `false` before you add it. Once it works it also lets you focus on other aspects of your code.

Comment: Yes, this would work, but you're assuming that the OP is allowed to use collections 

Comment: True,  But there weren't any constraints mentioned.

Comment: True, but the OP might not know about collections - given the amount of "home work" related questions lately, I'm also assuming 

Comment: I addressed that aspect in my updated answer.

Comment: PS not the down voter - not sure why some would based on the available information

Comment: Just another of my fan club expressing awe at.my prowess of elucidation.

Comment: Oh, you have those too 